# How do I get the value of the current select option in a jQuery UI tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, tooltip

In jQuery, I am trying to get the value of the 'val' attribute of the currently selected item in a select box, use that value to retrieve data and then display that data using a tooltip.

For testing purposes, when I run the following it gets the value just fine and works as expected:

```
$( 'select' )
.mouseover( function(){
    alert( $(this).val().trim() );
})
```

More, the following also works fine with a hardcoded parameter value:

```
$( 'select' ).tooltip({
       content: cellTooltipContent( '865' )
});
```

But when I try something like the following, Chrome Developer tools says that the parameter to the cellTooltipContent function is undefined.

```
$( 'select' ).tooltip({
       content: cellTooltipContent( $(this).val() )
});
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
$( 'select' ).tooltip({
       content: cellTooltipContent( $(this).find(':selected').text() )
});
```

It seems to think that **this** refers to **document** rather than the currently selected item. I've also tried **this.val** for the parameter, and a few dozen other things. I've worked on this for three days and I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your calls in an anonymous function:

```
$('select').tooltip({
    content: function() { return cellTooltipContent( $(this).val() )}
});
```

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fa9u/) example.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I wouldn't have guessed in a hundred years that it needed an extra function wrapper. The key, I suppose, is that content must be a 0-arity function that returns a string, rather than a value. Thanks so much, Richard.

Comment: But this is strange. The first example at http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content uses a value, not an IIFE. Does anyone have any idea why that is so? Very strange.

Comment: @citrus Yes, you can also pass strings to the 'content:' attribute.  However, hard-coded strings and functions are different types.  Internally, it checks if it's a string and sets the value.  If it's a function, it calls the function and sets the value to the return.  So, if you want to use your function, you need to wrap it.  (I think, due to parameters and scope... can't remember exaclty why at the moment.)

Comment: So I just plugged in `content: cellTooltipContent()` (with the parameter hard-coded in the function) and it works fine, except of course for the fact that it's not getting a parameter. So it looks like any function with zero parameters will work there as long as it returns a string. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @citrus That makes sense.  That means that when the code executes the callback, they don't pass parameters.  That would cause problems if your function requires parameters.  (It's been a while since I was debugging jQuery.)

Comment: @ Richard: So, to sum up my understanding, it looks like the envelope function is necessary to specify a function with zero parameters, which allows a wrapped function to specify parameters using jQuery selectors and functions. Makes sense now.